# Is Apache Synapse being planned to migrate to Java 11?

Tags: java-11, apache-synapse, azul-zulu

Is Apache Synapse updated as per Java 11 ?

- The latest release of Apache Synapse, dates to December 2017, which is from 3.0.1 version.
- While loading the classes from the jar, encountering ClassNotFoundException

  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Service

Answer (score 1):

sun.misc.Service is a JDK internal API and was removed in JDK 9.

A public API that provides identical functionality has been available since JDK 6 (java.util.ServiceLoader).  The Apache Synapse project should have been updated to use this (but, presumably, has not).

I don't know why this question is tagged as azul-zulu since it is not specific to those builds of OpenJDK (I work for Azul).